# Where does next_batch in the TensorFlow tutorial batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100) come from?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying out the TensorFlow tutorial and don't understand where does next_batch in this line come from?

```
 batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
```

I looked at

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

And didn't see next_batch there either.

Now when trying out next_batch in my own code, I am getting

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'next_batch'
```

So I would like to understand where does next_batch come from?

Comment: also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454511/tensorflow-how-is-dataset-train-next-batch-defined

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`next_batch` is a method of the `DataSet` class (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py for more information on what's in the class).

When you load the mnist data and assign it to the variable `mnist` with:

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

look at the class of `mnist.train`. You can see it by typing:

```
print mnist.train.__class__
```

You'll see the following:

```
<class 'tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist.Dataset'>
```

Because `mnist.train` is an instance of class `DataSet`, you can use the class's function `next_batch`. For more information on classes, check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 8):

After looking through the tensorflow repository, it seems to originate here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9230423668770036179a72414482d45ddde40a3b/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/sequence_queueing_state_saver.py#L905

However if you're looking to implement it in your own code (for your own dataset), it would likely be much simpler to write it yourself in a dataset object, as I did. As I understand it, it's a method to shuffle the entire dataset, and return $mini_batch_size number of samples from the shuffled dataset.

Here's some pseudocode:

`shuffle data.x and data.y while retaining relation
return [data.x[:mb_n], data.y[:mb_n]]`

Comment: Would you please elaborate? For example, say my images are all the same size of 512 x 256. How would you "shuffle while retaining relation"? What does that mean? What's the shape of the data.x[:mb_n] and data.y[:mb_n] returned in this list?

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the help function:

```
help(tf.contrib.learn.datasets.mnist.DataSet.next_batch)
```

and get the document of function next_batch